# Replace letter with alphabet position, why splice do not remove multiple characters

Tags: javascript, ascii

I have the following code.

```
var list = input => {
      let array = input.split('').map(ch => ch.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96);

      for(let el in array) {
        if(array[el] < 1 || array[el] > 26)
          array.splice(el,1);
      }
      return array.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ');
    }

    console.log(list("The sun!!!set sets at twelve o' clock."));
    // output
    //20 8 5 19 21 14 -63 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 -64 3 12 15 3 11
```

Why splice does not remove multiple characters in the row? Special characters are removed only if they occur between letters. How to change the code to achieve only posiotions of the letters from the alphabet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using splice() in a loop is not a good idea. You are changing the length of what you are looping over.

Use `filter()` instead to exclude the unwanted values. You can also use `join()` with  space delimiter.

```js
var list = input => {
  return input.split('')
    .map(ch => ch.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96)
    .filter(n => n > 0 && n < 27)
    .join(' ');
}

console.log(list("The sun!!!set sets at twelve o' clock."));
```

If you do want to splice() it is safest to do it working backwards through the array

```
for(let i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Then you won't change the indexing of the elements you haven't visited yet

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through the array by

```js
for(let el in array)
```

and you still remove the elements from *the same* array by

```js
array.splice(el,1);
```

You cannot do this because if you remove an element, the array becomes one element shorter, but this is not reflected in your iteration.

Instead, iterate normally by numeric element index (in loop condition still checking current length of the array) and either increase the index or remove the element:

```js
if(array[i] < 1 || array[o] > 26)
    array.splice(i,1)
else
    i++;
```